# can i do multipe write and multipe read to a zipped/compressed file

Tags: compression, zip

Is this possible without any consistency problem.
Which popular compression algorithm will best suite for these kind of purpose ?

Answer (score 0):

A compressed file system is the simplest way to do that. You can enable compression in NTFS, ZFS or BTRFS, depending on your OS. But the compression is not great.

A fast algorithm with an flexible container would also do. Zip seems workable: [How to update one file in a zip archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799553/how-to-update-one-file-in-a-zip-archive)