# Replace a single file from jar file

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd, jar

I need to replace a single class file from a jar file. The jar file is quite big and every time I don't want to extract it and replace manually.  I want to automate this procedure. Can someone please help me on this. 
When jar file is extracted below folders are created :

1. render
2. classes
3. com

I need to go  inside "com/cgp/f1/cmmi/" folder and replace a class file inside it.

Things I tried :

1. `zip file.jar com/cgp/f1/cmmi/services.class Services.class`
2. `jar uf  file.jar com/cgp/f1/cmmi/ services.class

   jar -uf  file.jar com\cgp\f1\cmmi\ services.class

   jar uf  file.jar com/cgp/f1/cmmi/services.class services.class`

The error I am getting is  :

> when using jar command
>   com\cgp\f1\cmmi\  : no such file or directory
>
> when using zip command :
>   zip warning: name not matched: com\cgp\f1\cmmi\Services.class

can some one please guide me where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe the `jar -uf` found here could help you: [How to update one file in a zip archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799553/how-to-update-one-file-in-a-zip-archive)

If graphical apps are an option, you could use winrar or 7-zip to replace the class. You don't need to extract the jar file to make this work. Just open the jar with one of those apps, go to de directory where is the class file to be replaced, drag-and-drop the new file to replace the old one and save.

Comment: The thing is, I want to update without using tools. Kind of automation.