# updating jar file with powershell

Tags: powershell

i am trying to update jar file with powershell but it corrupts file.

when i try replace a class in jar file with following method [System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions]::CreateEntryFromFile

java.exe cant load that specific class from jar.

but if update with 7zip then no problem occurs..

i noticed with powershell method it modifies Charecteristic tab so it not listed as descriptor for that specific class.

[jar screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dz9Zw.png)

code as below.

```
Add-Type -Assembly System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
$enc = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
$zipFile = [IO.Compression.ZipFile]::Open('.\destjar.jar',([System.IO.Compression.ZipArchiveMode]::Update),$enc)
$foundFile=$zipFile.Entries.Where({ $_.FullName -like '*dest.class' }, 'First')
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions]::ExtractToFile($foundFile[0], "temp.class",$true)


#some class modification here...

$foundFile.Delete()
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions]::CreateEntryFromFile($zipFile,'temp.class','com\xxx\yyy\zzz\dest.class')

$zipFile.Dispose()
```

Comment: If you are not limited to use PowerShell, you could try to use the 'jar' command. There is the option '-u or --update  Updates an existing JAR file.'. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799553/how-to-update-one-file-in-a-zip-archive for an example.

Comment: There are a few versions of the ZIP standard.  The ZIP standard also have optional features that not all tools support.  7ZIP is one of the best tools and supports multiple versions of specification as well as optional features.  Modifying a zip files often causes compatibility issues between different tools.  The file is not corrupt.  The issue is the tool you are using to modify the zip is not fully compatible with the tool you are using to unzip the file.

Comment: yes it is not corrupt but java cant find that class after modify. i have to use powershell. i cant use 7zip module either it must be vanilla powershell.

Comment: jar.exe is not portable . it requires certain msvc dll and destination systems may not have it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.